# Git: Discard all changes on a diverged local branch

Tags: git

I have a local topic branch that's tracking a remote branch. For the sake of argument, say the commit histories look like this:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (origin/phobos)
       \
         L1--L2--L3 (phobos)
```

Having looked at the relative commit histories, I now want to discard all the changes to the local `phobos` branch and get it back to being a direct copy of `origin/phobos`, so that the local history looks like this:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (phobos origin/phobos)
```

I really don't want the local changes to the `phobos` branch, and I really don't want any merges to show up in the origin repository afterwards. (So, just merging isn't what I have in mind.)

This seems like it should be really easy, but my google-fu has failed me.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Delete the branch, then recreate it:

```
$ git branch -D phobos
$ git checkout --track -b phobos origin/phobos
```

Be aware that deleting the branch blows away the branch's reflog.

Resetting the branch (like shown in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2358764/2805305)), on the other hand not only preserves the reflog, but actually records the reset in the reflog. This makes the operation easily reversible later, if needed.

Comment: A problem with this approach versus resetting the branch's head, is that deleting the branch blows away the branch's reflog. Resetting the branch, on the other hand not only preserves the reflog, but actually records the reset in the reflog. This makes the operation easily reversible later, if needed.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy Would suggest you change the accepted answer here to Dan's (so that people like me who've Googled how to do it are likely to choose the safer method).

Comment: @DanMoulding's answer doesn't involve deleting a local branch when it is unnecessary.  It is much safer.

Comment: @brma: How so? It's still just pointing a branch to a new commit.

Comment: Dan Moulding's answer is safer. I think you should select that one.

Comment: I think this exactly answers OP's question - it blats local history, not polluting the history with whatever local changes you had. Sometimes total amnesia is what you want. Having both answers is perfectly good, this way people get to decide what fits their needs

Comment: @hrillo666 Having both answers is good, but "accepted" implies it's the "best" answer which is what the discussion is about. No one has suggested deleting this answer. Also using `reset --hard` doesn't really "pollute" the history. It leaves reflog intact, but the history of the branch itself is reset entirely to that of the remote which is likely what you care about.

Answer (score 436):

```
git checkout phobos
git reset --hard origin/phobos
```

This tells Git to reset the head of `phobos` to the same commit as `origin/phobos`, and to update the working tree to match.

Comment: IMO this should be the accepted answer; it issues the "reset" command to transplant the branch pointer, instead of performing surgery with removing/recreating.

Comment: Actually, I tried this one first and it threw a ton of errors making by local copy nearly unusable.  Delete / recreate may have been less elegant, but I didn't have to ask any follow-up questions.

Comment: @Electrons_Ahoy: Hmm, that's definitely not normal. Doing this reset should normally be a problem-free operation if your repo is in good working order.

Comment: or even if it's hinky.  Use git reflog to find your way home if you "accidentally" issued this command without actually reading what it does.  **:)**

Comment: Also this works if you are on the branch and you messed it up locally.

Comment: I tried this and `git pull` still shows merge conflicts.

Comment: @Polyergic, there's only one way that can happen and that's if the remote branch you reset your local branch to match is not the same branch your local branch is configured to pull from.

Comment: Isnt `git fetch origin phobos` required before the reset? Otherwise you could end up resetting to a local version of phobos which is not what you wanted in this case.

Comment: @jonaz depends on what you mean by local and how it diverged. If the divergence happened locally it's not a problem because even if `origin/phobos` is out date it will "undo" the divergence and `git pull` will get you in sync with the remote. If the remote `phobos` was rebased or something and you want that version, then yes, you will need to `git fetch` before doing the reset to `origin/phobos`.