# Git: Discard all changes on remote branch and push local changes without force push

Tags: git, git-merge, git-remote

The case is similar to : [Git: Discard all changes on a diverged local branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358643/git-discard-all-changes-on-a-diverged-local-branch).

Differences:

- I want to discard changes which have been pushed to remote
  repository,
- `git push origin foo:foo --force` is rejected (origin
  doesn't allow force pushing).

Given commit graph:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (foo)
       \
         L1--L2--L3 (origin/foo)
```

I want to achieve this if possible:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (foo origin/foo)
```

If above is impossible then following is ok for me:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3--M1 (foo)
       \            /
         L1--L2--L3 (origin/foo)
```

but I want `git diff M1..03` be empty i.e. discard all changes introduced in `origin/foo`. And `-s ours` strategy doesn't help because this only works for conflicts and non-conflicting changes will still be added to `M1`.

How can I do this?

### [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39785439/5492820) (by [Mohan Kumar P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6551063/mohan-kumar-p))

Delete remote branch and push. `git` should create remote branch automatically if it's tracked (check `git branch -vv`).

To achieve this:

```
A--B--C--O1--O2--O3 (foo origin/foo)
       \
         L1--L2--L3
```

type:

```
git push origin --delete foo
git checkout foo  # Git ≥ 1.6.6.
git push origin foo
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply delete the remote branch and then push your local branch. I assume it is not restricted.

Comment: I'll check it out and if it works I will accept your solution. Otherwise I will update question with further details.

Comment: Came here from google and the below answer is perfect:

`git merge -s ours upstream/production`

Answer (score 7):

The `-s ours` strategy *does* work.  It's the `-X ours` "strategy argument" that does not work (for the reason you give).

I think calling these both `ours`, and then furthermore calling one a "strategy" and the other a "strategy argument" was at best poor planning, as it's confusing, to say the least.  (It arose because the `-X` values are arguments that are passed on to the driver selected by the `-s` argument—but this explanation just makes it even worse:  "The `-s` argument is the strategy and the `-X` arguments are the arguments to the strategy from the first argument."  "What, so they're argument arguments!? ... Wait, what are we arguing about again?")

Nonetheless, the `-s ours` strategy really does precisely what you're asking for: it pretends to merge, without even looking at the other branch.  Hence, if you are on branch `foo` whose upstream is `origin/foo` and you have the graph you have drawn as the starting position, then:

```
git merge -s ours origin/foo
```

(perhaps with an explicit `-m` message as well, or you can use the editor when it runs to explain the merge) will give you the final graph you drew.